# tflearn - fasttext word vector error in embedding layer

Tags: tflearn, fasttext

I am using fasttext word embeddings to create word vectors for sentences for a sentiment analysis binary classifier. Fasttext vectors have both negative and positive numbers.

My embedding layer is

```
net = embedding(net, input_dim=20000, output_dim=num_hidden)
```

However I get the error,

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[99,244] = -1 is not in [0, 20000)
 [[Node: Embedding/embedding_lookup = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Embedding/W"], validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Embedding/W/read, Embedding/Cast)]]
```

What does this error mean exactly?

I tried to make all the negative values in the word embedding 0, which although it does work, it loses a lot of information

I am not understanding how the input_dim works in the embedding layer in tflearn?

Also I don't understand how to use Fasttext word embeddings with tflearn?

Any help would be much appreciated